# react-router-dom@4.0.0 requires a peer of react@^15 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself

Tags: reactjs, react-router, npm-install, react-router-dom

I have installed all required libraries using `npm install` and I also done `npm install --save react-router-dom@4.0.0` but I am still getting this error.

My Package.json

```
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "4.3.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4"
  }
```

After updating react, redux, react-redux,and all I got no warnings but got following error after I ran `npm start`

```
> node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1258:14)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at net.js:1404:9
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:81:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! redux-simple-starter@1.0.0 start: `node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the redux-simple-starter@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myhome/.npm/_logs/2017-12-23T00_38_08_579Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hi @prezemek es I have npm version `5.5.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need React in your `package.json`

Try the following in the folder where your `package.json` is placed:

```
npm install react --save
```

If `react` is already present in your `package.json` verify that the version is higher then 15.0.

If that's not fixing your error, please provide us your `package.json`

Comment: after updating react version, I am getting following warnings:  
    npm WARN react-addons-test-utils@0.14.8 requires a peer of     react@^0.14.8 but none is installed.  You must install peer     dependencies yourself. -npm WARN react-dom@0.14.9 requires a peer     of react@^0.14.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.  
    npm WARN react-redux@4.3.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 but     none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: i think you have some unresolvable cyclic dependencies in your current project. Try to set up a fresh package.json with the latest redux/react/react-router dependencies if you don't depend on these older versions. Therefor don't forget to remove your `node_modules` folder. **BUT: Save your current package.json for a backup**

Comment: I installed all to the latest version, now no warnings but when I did `npm start` I am getting above response I added in question.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @rieckpil, I have followed following steps and it fixed my problem.

1: On this [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react) I collected latest version for all following libraries react, react-dom, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, redux and replaced it in my `package.json` file.

2: Run `npm install`

3: Run `npm start`. If getting errors like above, simply restart you computer and run `npm start` again.